# Generate Random color from select list

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I am trying to generate a random color for the result when the user selects a value from the select list.

```
 <div id="req7" class="req7">
 <select id="names">
 <option value="Name1">Name 1</option>
 <option value="Name2">Name 2</option>
 <option value="Name3">Name 3</option>
 <option value="Name4">Name 4</option>
 </select><br><br>
 <p>Click the button to return the value of the selected headline.    </p><br>
 <button class="styled-button" type="button"  onclick="headline()">Submit</button><br>
 <br><br>
 <h1 id="here"></h1>
 </div>

function headline(){
var nemo = document.getElementById("names").value;
var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
var color = '#';
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
  color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
 }
 return color;
 document.getElementById("here").innerHTML = nemo;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a `return color;` before `document.getElementById("here").innerHTML = nemo;`.

Here, this should work:

```
function headline(){
  var nemo = document.getElementById("names").value;
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
    color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
   }
   document.getElementById("here").innerHTML = nemo;
   return color;
}
```

Plus your code has `onc lick`.

`<button class="styled-button" type="button" onc lick="headline()">Submit</button` should be
`<button class="styled-button" type="button" onclick="headline()">Submit</button`

https://output.jsbin.com/zunowuvede

Comment: I figured it out. i was my css it was overriding javascript